# Webpack doesn't understand React's syntax

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am learning both React and Webpack. Now I have written a component that displays a name ;-)

```
const app = document.getElementById('app');

class World extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.name = 'Tomek';

    this.callByName = this.callByName.bind(this); /* Or bind directly when calling */
  }

  callByName() {
    alert(this.name);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Hello, {this.name}</h2>
        <button onClick={this.callByName}>Alert</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<World />, app);
```

I import it with React and ReactDOM:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import './components/posts/index.js';
```

I use Webpack to process my JS:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './_babel/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/_js',
        filename: 'index.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' }
        ]
    }
};
```

Unfortunately, when I run `webpack`, I get

```
ERROR in ./_babel/components/posts/index.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /Users/tomek/Sites/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Devoid/_babel/components/posts/index.js: Unexpected token (17:6)
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Hello, {this.name}</h2>
        <button onClick={this.callByName}>Alert</button>
      </div>
```

Propably I just forgot something, but I can't seem to find what.

Comment: Which version of babel.. 5 or 6?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the react loader to your webpack.config.js. I also suggest adding ES2015 loader. Try this:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './_babel/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/_js',
        filename: 'index.js'
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          query: {presets: ['es2015']}
        },
        {
          test: /\.jsx$/,
          loader:'babel-loader',
          query: {presets: ['es2015', 'react']}
        }
      ]
    }
};
```

Comment: You're totally right! I forgot to specify the Babel presets ;-) Thank you! I used `.babelrc` file though.